# How to fix "Request server is wrong" error in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I want to active Paypax payment gateway in my site,
I've activated my account in Paypax and used the codes that they gave to me to activate gateway but it doesn't connect to payment gateway with this error:"Request server is wrong"

Please check this codes:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://paypax.net/cp/api/checkout/create');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($RequestData));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// decode response
$response = json_decode($response);
// check is response ok
if($response->code == 200){
    /*
     * Do this:
     * Store $response->token at table
     * and redirect user to $response->url
     */

}else{
    /*
     * fix error
     */
}
```

After executing code I receive these results:
    $response-> message == "Request server is wrong"
    $response-> status == "false"
    $response-> code == "403"

Please tell me is there any problem with codes?
Does my server needs something to execute this codes?

Comment: Without more information, it's really hard to tell. Contact their support with your request information, and they can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: If the code is correct you will never get a code 200 as you always overwrite your `$response` with your last 3 lines

Comment: I have no idea what is Romain talking about, but the problem seems not to be connected directly to your code. That is what server returns. You are probably using their API incorrect way.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Paypax support doesn't answer my questions, their FAQ and User Manual pages not found (with error 404), So I don't know what can I do. this is the documentation page: https://paypax.net/developers and the complete code is in the "Getting Started" section.